# "TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type" while counting mean and median

Tags: python, numpy

```
import numpy as np
f = open('output.txt', 'w')
a = np.genfromtxt('input.txt')
print("{:.2f}".format(np.median(a)), file = f)
print("{:.2f}".format(np.mean(a)), file = f)
print("{:.2f}".format(np.std(a)), file = f, end = '')
f.close()
```

I've got this code, and it says that 4th line has this error (I presume 5th and 6th too), but I don't understand what it means.

Comment: What is the content of `a` ?

Comment: You need to show a reproducible example, so we will need to see the contents of `input.txt`

Comment: And also please always add the full error message to your questions. Check [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.